# Validation error code 2011 wp8 while submitting app to the store

Tags: windows-phone-8

My app validation failed due to error 2011 (Windows Phone 8 App).
I got the following error for a no. of times:

2011: The background agent can’t use Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame::RemoveBackEntry, which assembly MyApp.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try again.

Can anybody tell as to how to get rid of this error and pass the validation?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: do you use removebackentry in your background agent?

Comment: no, i have my main project in which i have background player classes in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use some API in Background Agents - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). And one which you cannot use is:

> System.Windows.Navigation ->  All APIs in this namespace are unsupported.

And as you can see [PhoneApplicationFrame.RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.removebackentry) returns `System.Windows.Navigation.JournalEntry`.